# Translation of "junket"

Tags: traduction

What's the translation of “junket” in French?

From https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/junket ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191122202021/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/junket)):

> *Informal.* An extravagant trip or celebration, in particular one enjoyed by government officials at public expense. Example: ‘the latest row over city council junkets’.

I looked at a few dictionaries but found nothing.

Comment: [" Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question"](https://french.stackexchange.com/help)  What have you found?

Comment: J'ai trouvé l'expression *voyage aux frais de la princesse* ( linguee). J'ignore si cela correspond à ce que vous cherchez

Comment: @Damien thanks, not too bad but it's not very clear that the taxpayers is paying for this, and also I'm not sure whether the extravagance is well conveyed. But perhaps that's because I wasn't aware of that expression.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is in French no short one word term for "junket". The long term that will do as a translation is "voyage officiel aux frais de la princesse".

Of course, you can also say "voyage officiel aux frais du contribuable", but it's not sarcastic.